# automatic set python module path like maven?

Tags: python, path, pythonpath

in maven, when I run tests, the sources in src/ are automatically sourced.

now I organize my python code in a similar dir structure. but when I run unitttests,
python -m unittests tests
it says that the classes being tested can not be found.

how I can let it find the source?

(well I could write a shell script and set PYTHONPATH, but I don't know if that's
the idiomatic way of doing it in python)

thanks
Yang

Comment: this question is probably impossible to answer without seeing directory structure and error messages and the directory you are running from...

Comment: thanks, my code structure is like this:    BASE_DIR/src/module1.py  , BASE_DIR/src/module2.py  , BASE_DIR/tests/test_module1.py  , BASE_DIR/tests/test_module2.py.  the error is like "
....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/key_mgr/tests/test_yaml.py", line 3, in <module>
    from YamlConfig import *
ImportError: No module named YamlConfig

Comment: YamlConfig is a class I defined in src/YamlConfig.py